covering space of torus
What is the covering space of the torus $T = S^1 \times S^1 $ corresponding to the subgroup $2\mathbb {Z} \times 2\mathbb {Z} $ of $ \mathbb {Z} \times \mathbb {Z} $?
Here is my explanation, is it correct ?
The torus $T $ can be represented as $ \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$, where the fundamental group of the torus $ \pi_1(T) $ is $ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup $ 2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z} $ is an index 4 subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, which means the corresponding covering space will be a 4-fold cover of the torus.
The universal cover of $ T = S^1 \times S^1$ is $ \mathbb{R}^2 $.
And the fundamental group $ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} $ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by translations. Specifically, $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2) by
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (x + m, y + n).
$$
We consider the action of $ 2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z} $ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $(2m, 2n) \in 2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (x + 2m, y + 2n).
$$
By taking the quotient $ \mathbb{R}^2 / (2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z})$,  the fundamental domain will be a $ 2 \times 2 $ square instead of the unit square.
The covering map $ p: \mathbb{R}^2 / (2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2 $ is given by:
$$
p(x, y) = (x \mod 1, y \mod 1).
$$
This map wraps the $ 2 \times 2 $ square fundamental domain onto the unit square by identifying points that differ by integers.

For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution, "Is it correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Any finite covering space of the torus $T = S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to the torus $T$ itself. One way of seeing this is as follows:

A finite covering space of a compact oriented surface is a compact oriented surface.
The Euler characteristic $\chi$ of the compact oriented surface $S_g$ of genus $g \geq 0$ is $\chi(S_g)=2-2g$.
For any topological spaces $X,Y$, if there is an $n$-sheeted covering map $Y \to X$, then $\chi(Y) = n \chi(X)$.
The torus is the compact oriented surface of genus one: $T = S_1$.


is my above explanation correct ?
